# Need JDBC Driver Class for LibreOffice Calc (Database)

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, sql

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and LibreOffice Calc.
Trying to connect to database, which is Microsoft SQL which I am using through DBeaver.

I would like to know what to write here:

[image]

I have tried installing [Microsoft Drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774).

Answer (score 0):

Use [JTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html).

```
Interface                           jTDS Implementation
java.sql.Driver                     net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
javax.sql.DataSource                net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource
javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource  net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource
javax.sql.XADataSource              net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource
javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsObjectFactory
```

The URL format for jTDS:

```
jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
```

- server_type is "sqlserver" for MSSQL.
- See the link for a description of all the options.
- [Driver download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/)